# encoding in python: what type is the variable

Tags: python, encoding

Python file

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
a = 'Köppler'
print a
print a.__class__.__name__
mydict = {}
mydict['name'] = a
print mydict
print mydict['name']
```

Output:

```
Köppler
str
{'name': 'K\xc3\xb6ppler'}
Köppler
```

It seems that the name remains the same, but only when printing a dictionary I get this strange escaped character string. What am I looking at then? Is that the UTF-8 representation?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for that behavior is that the `__repr__` function in Python 2 [escapes non-ASCII unicode characters](http://bugs.python.org/issue2630). As the link shows, this is fixed in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's the UTF-8 representation of `ö` (U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS).  It consists of a 0xC3 octet followed by a 0xB6 octet.  [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a very elegant encoding, I think, and worth reading up on.  The history of its design (on a placemat in a diner) is [described here by Rob Pike](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/utf-8-history.txt).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned there are two methods in Python for displaying objects: str() and repr(). Str() is used internally inside print, however Apparently dict's str() uses repr() for keys and values.

As it has been mentioned: repr() escapes unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using python 2.x, where you have to specify that the object is actually a unicode string and not a plain ascii. You specified that the *code* is utf-8, thus you actually typed 2 bytes for your ö, and as it is a regular string, you got the 2 escaped chars.
Try to specify the unicode `a= u'Köppler'`. You may need to encode it before printing, depending on your consol encoding: `print a.encode('utf-8')`